# Как смещать указатель чтения из бинарного файла на четные позиции?

Tags: c++

Надо считывать из бинарного файла числа, которые стоят на четных позициях. Надо использовать seekg(), но как она работает, можете объяснить? Что нужно поставить вместо многоточия?

```
while (!f.eof())
{
    f.seekg(........, ios::beg);
}
```

Comment: Смещение от позиции, которую вы указали вторым параметром. http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg

Comment: @Harry, не совсем понял. Как сделать так, чтобы seekg было только на четных позициях?

Comment: Так... придется начать сначала. Что такое четное число, знаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модификатор `ios::beg` устанавливает указатель в позицию от начала потока. А Вам нужно использовать `ios::cur` чтобы сместиться от текущей позиции. Если после чтения сместиться на 1 от текущей позиции то четность позиции изменяться не будет.

Итого

```
f.seekg(1, ios::cur);
```

Comment: Думаю, что под "четными позициями" имеются в виду не абсолютные позиции в файлах, а позиции чисел в последовательности. Так вы будете читать не числа, а какие-то перепутаницы...